# Stripping JSON encoding of PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL query done using PHP, result is presented as array.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT word FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
    $stmt->bind_result($words);

$stmt->execute();
$result = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $w = new StdClass();
    $w->word = $words;
    array_push($result, $w);
}
$stmt->close();
```

Then, i'm passing the array to javascript using JSON:

```
'words' : <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>,
```

But the output is:

```
[{"word":"Watermelon"},{"word":"Orange"},{"word":"Melon"},{"word":"Cucumber"},{"word":"Apple"}]
```

Is there any way to "strip" the "word" and make it look like that?

```
["Watermelon", "Orange", "Melon", "Cucumber", "Apple"]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need array of objects (`$w`s) further in your code, you can simplify your code to:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT word FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
$stmt->bind_result($words);

$stmt->execute();
$result = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    array_push($result, $words);
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Thank you! Apparently i overcomplicated things :)

Comment: If answer helps - feel free to accept it, as answers for your previous questions. It helps both you and answerer)